# Create a connected graph of common DBpedia entities

Tags: python, d3.js, sparql, rdf, dbpedia

My problem is such: Say I have 4 entities: Renoir, Newton, Leibniz and Pissaro. I need to create a connected graph of all entities common to them from the Dbpedia Ontology.

Example: This is a connected graph between Renoir and Pissaro from DBPedia. The nodes in between are the DBPedia schema's common to both. See image: http://postimg.org/image/6037y9lu1/

We need such a graph between the 4: Renoir, Newton, Leibniz and Pissaro. 
http://postimg.org/image/vud0o1lu1/

How should this be done?

I’m novice to DPPedia, R or anything related. Any help is useful.

My objective of doing this is to find transitive connections between entities at conceptual level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use relFinder? (http://www.visualdataweb.org/relfinder/relfinder.php) It serves precisely this purpose. I attach the graph I obtained when I introduced the four entities in your example:
[image: Example using Leibniz, Newton, Pissaro and Renoir]

As you can see, if you want to find a connection between them at a conceptual level you should aim for the "influencedBy"/"influences" relationship.